# knockout - binding from input tu viewModel?

Tags: knockout.js

I have knockout viewModel:

```
function vm() {
 this.text = ko.observable("defualt text"); 
}
```

and my html

```
<input data-bind="value: text" />
<span data-bind="text: text" />
```

when I have my instance of vm in javascript and call for

vm.text() - output is "default text" which is ok,

now - when I change the text in the input field - so is span text changing - it's ok, but if I call vm.text() - the output is still "default text".

My question: Is there any way that I could make it automatic two-way binding?

Answer (score 0):

try to read this "knockout update observable"

[Knockout observable change not detected if value changed externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846103/knockout-observable-change-not-detected-if-value-changed-externally)

here the demo

jsfiddle.net/tlarson/GF3Xe/

Answer (score 0):

By default **change** event of input is triggered on blur (focus drop), but you can force knockout to listen another event. Try this:

```
data-bind="value: text, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
```