# Observable array not getting reflected in UI in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a observable array which has 2 observable properties. I am able to update the array when placing an input box through the UI as below

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Scopes.ScopesData">
                <tr style="vertical-align: baseline">
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap"><span data-bind="text: name" /></td>
                    <td>                               
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: HeadCountFlag, enable: isAvailable" />


   </td>                                
                    <td>                                 
                        <input data-bind="textInput: HeadCountpercent, enable: isAvailable" class="amount" /> 
                   </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

In here ScopesData is an observable array and the 2 properties HeadCountFlag
and HeadCountpercent are also observable.

I am able to make a change to it and see it getting updated as below

```
<span data-bind="text: Scopes.ScopesData()[0].HeadCountpercent()"></span>
```

Now I want to update this through some javascript code when some event happens 
and I am able to change the data and it gets saved also but it is not being reflected in the UI.

```
 model.Scopes.ScopesData._latestValue[0].HeadCountpercent._latestValue = 99;
```

Can someone please tell me what change do I need to make to have this Scopes.ScopesData()[0].HeadCountpercent() update from the js code and see it get updated in the UI.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make what you're changing an observable, and change it via that observable.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: Both the ScopesData array and the HeadCountpercent property is observable. Can you please tell me exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: I'm referring to *the thing you're changing*, which is `_latestValue`.

Comment: Sorry if I am sounding stupid..I just got this code handed over and I am very new to knockout so not very clear on things.

Comment: I suggest going through the tutorial on http://knockoutjs.com/. It's a very good introduction to KO.

Comment: Thanks for your changing value of observable pointer..got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access `_latestValue`. To write a new value to the `observable`, you need call the `observable` and pass the new value as an argument.

```
model.Scopes.ScopesData()[0].HeadCountpercent(99);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/11udd5L9/5/) for testing. I have added a button, which will call a javascript function to update `ScopesData`'s first `index` with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer by referring this thread [Knockout observable change not detected if value changed externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846103/knockout-observable-change-not-detected-if-value-changed-externally)

Basically I can set the value using 
model.Scopes.ScopesData._latestValue[0].HeadCountpercent(99);

Comment: I'm guessing you should do the same with ScopesData as well. The built in _latestValue property isn't something that should ever be used except for debugging purposes.